# Powershell command shown different behavior in console and script execution

Tags: powershell

I am doing a powershell script where it will trigger a product specific command and manipulate the returned result. The example of the returned result will look like the following

```
XXXX command completed  Thu Jan 13 16:59:59 2022 :XXXX, Account 'XXXX' on 'XXXX' modified successfully
```

So if the result contain modified successfully, it will do task A or vice versa based on the result. But I cant get the expected output when I run it inside my powershell script. Please refer to my script below

```
write-host "The type of variable :"$eTSuspend.GetType().Name
write-host "The string : "$eTSuspend.Contains('successfully')
```

FYI, `$eTSuspend` is the variable store the returned result by the command and here are my output from my script

```
The type of variable : Object[]
The string :  False
```

I tried to check the data type of the variable but it shown `Object[]` and the string validation shown false. So I am bit confused because the result is different from what I executed all the powershell command directly in the powershell console. Here are the step I did in my powershell console 
1) Copied the returned result and assigned to `$eTSuspend` manually
2) Executed $eTSuspend.GetType().Name
   - Yes,its a string data type 
3) $eTSuspend.Contains('successfully')
  - Yes, result returned true

```
PS C:\Users\XXX.XXX> $eTSuspend.GetType().Name
String
PS C:\Users\XXX.XXX> $eTSuspend.Contains("successfully")
True
```

I really cant figured out why both of the same command `GetType()` and `-Contains` returned a different result when I executed with script and powershell console

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of the Powershell script too. Looks like `$eTSuspend` is an array of objects in the script, but on the command line it's a plain string.

Comment: Also, make start each "console and script" with a fresh (restart) session.

Comment: Since your string returns as an Object, make use of -match operator or indexof

Comment: Did you try to call toString on your object or pass it to `Out-String`? In an interactive session it's not that uncommon that output can be a bit odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing for two different *kinds* of containment.

- [`String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) performs a *substring search* - if the substring argument is found at any offset in the string, it returns true:

  - `"abc def".Contains("def")` returns `$true`, because the susbtring `"def"` can be extracted from `"abc def"` at offset 4.
- [`Array.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.contains) and the `-contains` operator tests for *collection containment* - that is, "does this array/list/collection contain **an exact copy** of the argument among it's members":

  - `@("abc", "def").Contains("def")` returns true because at least one of the items in the array satisfies that constraint - `"def"` and `"def"` are equivalent
  - `@("abc", "def").Contains("de")` returns false because none of the items in the array is exactly equivalent to `"de"`, in other words:

    - `"abc" -eq "de"` is not true
    - `"def" -eq "de"` is not true either
    - There are no more items in the array to be tested, so it returns `$false`